# Erase and rewrite over and over again the text and card number in the same location in turtle graphics?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, overwrite

A concentration game requires users to be able to turn a card over many times before they correctly match it with the matching card.  This was not working consistently? It worked the first time a card was turned and immediately there after but if this card was skipped over one turn than  there after was undefined behavior.

```
import turtle
from turtle import *
import tkinter.font
from tkinter import *
import time

t = turtle.Turtle()
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=800, height=800, startx=10, starty=10)
eraseble = []

''' this function allows the square to be erased and rewriten '''
def erasableWrite(tortoise, name, font, align, reuse=None):
    eraser = turtle.Turtle() if reuse is None else reuse
    eraser.hideturtle()
    eraser.up()
    eraser.setposition(tortoise.position())
    eraser.write(name, font=font, align=align)
    print('eraser = {} name = {}.'.format(eraser, name))
    return eraser

startX = -280
startY = -295
textValue = [('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b'), ('3', 'c')]
t.hideturtle()
turtle.speed(0)
t.penup()
counter = 0
count = 0
for n in range(3):
    t.goto(startX, startY)
    t.pendown()
    eraseble.append(erasableWrite(t, textValue[n][0], font=("New Times Roman", 18, "normal"), align="center"))
    print('count = {}, eraseble[counter] = {} counter = {} n = {} textvalue = {}.  '.format(count, eraseble[counter], counter, n, textValue[n][0]))
    time.sleep(2)
    count += 1
    eraseble[counter].clear()
    eraseble.append(erasableWrite(t, textValue[n][1], font=("New Times Roman", 18, "normal"), align="center"))
    time.sleep(2)
    eraseble[counter + 1].clear()
    print('eraseble[counter] = {} counter = {} n = {} textvalue = {}.  '.format(eraseble[counter], counter, n, textValue[n][1]))
    eraseble[counter -1] = (erasableWrite(t, textValue[n][0], font=("New Times Roman", 18, "normal"), align="center"))
    count +=1
    startX +=40   
    startY += 20
    t.penup()
    counter +=2

    
` replace 1 with a `
startX = -280
startY = -295
t.goto(startX, startY)
print('count = {}, eraseble[0] = {}'.format(count, eraseble[0]))
count +=1
eraseble[0].clear()
textVal = textValue[0][0]
eraseble[0] = (erasableWrite(t, textVal, font=("New Times Roman", 18, "normal"), align="center"))
print('count = {}, eraseble[0] = {}'.format(count, eraseble[0]))
count +=1
eraseble[0].clear()
textVal = textValue[0][1]
eraseble[1] = (erasableWrite(t, textVal, font=("New Times Roman", 18, "normal"), align="center"))
time.sleep(2)

print('\n\neraseble = {}   !...!'.format(eraseble))
```

Comment: Can you make the problem clearer? What are you really asking to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing how the return value, and `reuse` argument to `erasableWrite` work.  I've rewritten your example code below (exaggerating the font and distances slightly):

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
import time

FONT = ("New Times Roman", 24, "bold")

def erasableWrite(tortoise, name, font, align, reuse=None):
    eraser = Turtle() if reuse is None else reuse
    eraser.hideturtle()
    eraser.up()
    eraser.setposition(tortoise.position())
    eraser.write(name, font=font, align=align)

    return eraser

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=800, height=800, startx=10, starty=10)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.penup()

erasable = []

startX = -280
startY = -295
textValue = [('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b'), ('3', 'c')]

for n in range(3):
    turtle.goto(startX, startY)

    erasable.append(erasableWrite(turtle, textValue[n][0], font=FONT, align="center"))
    time.sleep(2)
    erasable[n].clear()

    erasableWrite(turtle, textValue[n][1], font=FONT, align="center", reuse=erasable[n])
    time.sleep(2)
    erasable[n].clear()

    erasableWrite(turtle, textValue[n][0], font=FONT, align="center", reuse=erasable[n])

    startX += 80
    startY += 40

time.sleep(2)

startX = -280
startY = -295
turtle.goto(startX, startY)

erasable[0].clear()
textVal = textValue[0][1]
erasableWrite(turtle, textVal, font=FONT, align="center", reuse=erasable[0])
time.sleep(2)

erasable[0].clear()
textVal = textValue[0][0]
erasableWrite(turtle, textVal, font=FONT, align="center", reuse=erasable[0])
time.sleep(2)

screen.mainloop()
```

It displays the three "cards" and their values, and then goes back and exposes the first card's value again before covering it up.

Comment: Excellent! #cdiane you solved my problem.  Using your code I was able to switch back and forth 10 times perfectly.  WOW!  Thank you, thank you, thank you!